# What happens if you have an API endpoint with high response time called 100s of times?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm working on an app with an endpoint that syncs a large set of data at once via an endpoint. The response time is 8k ms (pretty high). I wonder what will happen if the user base grows from several dozen users to 100s or 1000s? What would happen with an endpoint that responds so slow. Will this hurt the performance of the app?

This is for a Node.js Express app built with Warp Server.

Comment: We don't do your work for you. Please read the help center before posting.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you've deployed it. if you have 1000 machines working in parallel, each taking 8s to respond, when you have 1000 users, it will still take 8s.

If however; you are doing this all on one machine, and the system resources are being completely used up for that 8s, then of course, two requests will take 16s, and three requests will take 24s and so on :P

This is a question of scalability, and the simple answer is, **it depends**. The biggest dependency is what is actually happening for those 8s while that app is responding.

Comment: Thank you, testing this out right now. Any chance you know if I can see in New Relic whether all endpoints are called in sequence or whether it's somewhat parallelized?

Comment: It really depends on what your app does. You've provided very little information about the nature of your app, so there isn't a huge amount anybody could reasonably say about the scalability of your app.